# Decimal value become another value

Tags: asp.net, parameters, sqldatasource

Why when i pass this parameter to sqldatasource parameters i see the correct defaultvalue but an incorrect parameter value? i don't know the difference between these two types of parameters, i Always think that default value is what is for my interest. I want to send in DB value 7.5 and not 75, could anyone help me please?

```
Parameter prm_prezzo = new Parameter("cc_prezzo", DbType.Decimal, newValues["PREZZO"].ToString().Replace(",", "."));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved but i would an expert's think about this because it's not clear for me:

the first instruction that i post had the replace of "," with "." because without the replace the "," escape the stored procedure

doing so...

```
Parameter prm_prezzo = new Parameter("cc_prezzo", DbType.Decimal);
prm_prezzo.DefaultValue = newValues["PREZZO"].ToString();
```

...i have the correct value and the stored procedure is not escaped...

but i don't undestand the difference between the two methods :-0